# Is there a way to get Selenium record to work consistently?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, web-testing

Following [this tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/blog/selenium-ide-tutorial/), I tried to record opening the Google home page. The first time it worked, but afterwords it no longer recorded the exact same action, even though the record button was definitely activated. I've tried restarting the browser and the Selenium IDE. Is there a trick to make this work every time?

Firefox is version 31.0. Selenium IDE is version 2.5.0.

Comment: What was the exact difference between the two actions? You will have to show us the recordings for us to tell.

Comment: @BobDalgleish There were no differences between the two actions. The first result was a correctly record "open" event. The second result was no recording at all.